# How do I print unprintable web pages?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, printing, webpage

I want to print out a web page that seems to be unprintable in both Firefox and Chrome.

It is multiple pages but when I print it out in Firefox and Chrome, they only print the first page.  The only way I have found to print out the page is to print it in IE in XPS Document Writer format.

Is there a way to do this in Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Is the page using frames? If yes, you might have to tell the browser to print the frame (rightlick -> print frame (or something like this)) instead of the whole page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As said in my comment, browsers have a problem to print web pages which contain multiple frames and will only print as long as all frames are visible.

To print a single (longer) frame, you have to tell the browser to print it without the others. You can do so by rightclicking into the frame you want to print and choose "Current Frame" -> "Print Frame" (text might vary for other browsers than Firefox)

Answer (score 3):

There is a very useful plugin for Firefox called Print Edit, that allows you to preview pages and then modify the output to suit your needs. You can find it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/

I often use this as an intermediary step, then save as PDF.

Comment: Very useful plugin. Managed to print an itinerary that otherwise would look horrible and consume 50% more pages.

Answer (score 2):

Take a screenshot (Windows 7, search for snipping tool). Save as jpeg, and print it.

Comment: This does not work very well for multi-page web sites.

Comment: @user1413 in firefox/seamonkey you can use [ScreenGrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab-fix-version/) to get a picture of an entire webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You can also right click in the frame that you want printed and select print (if right clicking hasn't been disabled).  At least that used to work in old versions of IE not sure if it's still like that now with other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Good solution to print webpages using screen capture in Firefox. The page will be printed as an image. It will not be possible to grab any text, but it is possible to make pretty accurate pdf copies of entire webpages.

1. In Firefox, start web console.
   Menu:Tools->Web Developer-> Web Console
2. Add "Take a fullpage screenshot" to console:
   Settings (click on gear)->Available toolbox buttons:enable "Take a full page screenshot". Now a photo camera appears on the Web console control bar.
3. Click the Web console "Photo camera" to take a full screenshot.
4. Use Firefox to open the .png file saved in the Download or the default Firefox directory:
   Second button click (chose "Open with: Firefox"): C:\temp\Screen Shot 2016-02-09 at 17.05.06.png
5. Click on the picture to apply the + Zoom.
6. In Firefox:
   Menu:File->Print preview
7. In Print preview screen adjust the zoom scale if needed to fit the width of the screen.
8. Print to pdf using Freepdf or PDFcreator. This will create a multi-page pdf file.

Comment: Too helpful for webpages that restricts print command. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome hit Print. Then change destination to 'save as PDF'

Open the saved PDF in Acrobat, then print all pages.

Does this work for those previously unprintable?

If so no add ons or screengrabs required.